# How to append multiple dictionaries into a single comma separated list using loop in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, jupyter-notebook

I have three jpeg images (image_1,image_2 and image_3) in my directory.

I want to have a list of dictionaries like this

```
 [{'doc_id': 1, 'doc_path': 'E:\\Python_data\\image_data\\Image_1.jpeg'},
  {'doc_id': 1, 'doc_path': 'E:\\Python_data\\image_data\\Image_2.jpeg'},
  {'doc_id': 1, 'doc_path': 'E:\\Python_data\\image_data\\Image_3.jpeg'}]
```

I have tried this in jupyter notebook

```
import cv2 
import os 
import glob 
img_dir = "E:\Python_data\image_data"
data_path = os.path.join(img_dir,'*g') 
files = glob.glob(data_path) 
for i in files:
   dict1 = {"doc_id": 1,"doc_path": i}
   list1=[]
   list1.append(dict1.copy())
print(list1,'<--My list')
```

But, I get this result:

```
[{'doc_id': 1, 'doc_path': 'E:\\Python_data\\image_data\\Image_3.jpeg'}] <--My list
```

I get only the last image appended to my list whereas previous images are getting replaced. Can anyone help me append properly? Thanks alot

Comment: Initialise `list1` before the loop.

Comment: Thanks alot matszwecja. That worked!!